# Print in insert mode python

Tags: python, terminal

How can i print something in the terminal/cmd in the insert mode?

I'm building a simple terminal chat, to run on **Windows and Linux**.
If Client A is typing a message, 'aloha', and during this the Client B sends a message, 'hello', before Client A press return (enter key), 'hello\n' should appear in the Client A's terminal, above (before) the 'aloha'.
For the carriage return I'm using '\rhello\n', but it overrides 'aloha' on the screen (altought if Client A press return 'aloha' is sent to Client B).

The solution to this is change from overwrite mode to insert mode while printing 'hello', so the flow when a message is received should be something like this: carriage return, activate insert mode, print 'hello', print newline (\n), deactivate insert mode (activate overwrite mode).

After about 3 hours searching how to do this in Python I gave up and came here.
By the way, I'm using 2 threads, one that prints the received message from Client B and another one to get the Client A's input.

Comment: Is this a problem of python or the terminal itself? I think you would have to create a GUI to fix this but not sure.

Comment: I don't think this is a "problem". The terminal probably is not the best thing to use, and I don't know, but I guess that it's not easy in another languages. In fact, a GUI would be the perfect choice, but it's a college work, so it must be this way (Python + terminal)

Comment: I don't think this problem is fixable since terminal isn't intended to be used this way. Well it's probably fixable but not worth the time. You could mention it in your report/code doc or just ignore it in general lol